# Preventing Multiple Requests and Updating

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

In the provided code, there seems to be an issue where the getOpenHours function is being called multiple times in quick succession when a date is selected. Additionally, the openHours Array is being updated with the same value repeatedly. This behavior should be modified to only execute the function when the date is changed, and to update the openHoursArray accordingly. Help is needed to resolve this issue and ensure that the getOpenHours function is only called when the date is changed.

```
const RoomDetailsPage = ({ route }) => {
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const [selectedStartHour, setSelectedStartHour] = useState(null);
  const [selectedEndHour, setSelectedEndHour] = useState(null);
  const [startHour, setStartHour] = useState(null);
  const [endHour, setEndHour] = useState(null);
  const [isDatePickerVisible, setDatePickerVisible] = useState(false);
  const { roomId } = route.params;
  const { placeId } = route.params;
  const { roomDetails } = route.params;
  const startDate = roomDetails.days[0].date.split("T")[0];
  const endDate =
    roomDetails.days[roomDetails.days.length - 1].date.split("T")[0];
  const [openHours, setOpenHours] = useState([]);

  const handleDateChange = async (date) => {
    const formattedDate = date.replace(/\//g, "-");
    const selectedDate = new Date(formattedDate);
    const hours = await getOpeningHours(selectedDate);
    setOpenHours(hours);
    setSelectedStartHour(null);
    setSelectedEndHour(null);
    setStartHour(null);
    setEndHour(null);
  };

  const getOpeningHours = async (date) => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        `https://spacezone-backend.cyclic.app/api/booking/getOpenHours/${placeId}`,
        { Date: date }
      );
      return response.data.openHoursArray;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      return [];
    }
  };
return (
         <View>
            <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Select Date</Text>
            <Text>Selected Date is {selectedDate}</Text>
            <DatePicker
            {/* This was imported from "react-native-modern-datepicker" */}
              onSelectedChange={handleDateChange}
              options={{
                backgroundColor: "#090C08",
                textHeaderColor: "#FFA25B",
                textDefaultColor: "#F6E7C1",
                selectedTextColor: "#fff",
                mainColor: "#F4722B",
                textSecondaryColor: "#D6C7A1",
                borderColor: "rgba(122, 146, 165, 0.1)",
              }}
              current="2023-06-01"
              mode="calendar"
              minimumDate={startDate}
              maximumDate={endDate}
              minuteInterval={30}
              style={{ borderRadius: 10 }}
            />
          </View>

          {/* List of selectable hours */}
          {openHours && openHours.length > 0 ? (
            <>
              <Text style={styles.subtitle}>Select Hours</Text>
              <View style={styles.hoursContainer}>
                {openHours.map((hour) => (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    key={hour}
                    style={[
                      styles.hourCard,
                      hour === selectedStartHour || hour === selectedEndHour
                        ? styles.selectedHourCard
                        : null,
                    ]}
                    onPress={() => handleHourPress(hour)}
                  >
                    <Text>{hour}:00</Text>
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                ))}
              </View>
            </>
          ) : (
            <Text>Loading open hours...</Text>
          )}
        </View>
);
```

i have tried so many things and i didn't solve the problem , if someone know the problem and how to solve it please tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try using the async function inside a `useEffect` hook like this:

```
const [date, setDate] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
    if (date){
        const formattedDate = date.replace(/\//g, "-");
        const selectedDate = new Date(formattedDate);

        const getOpeningHours = async () => {
            try {
              const response = await axios.post(
                `https://spacezone-backend.cyclic.app/api/booking/getOpenHours/${placeId}`,
                { Date: date }
              );
               setOpenHours(response.data.openHoursArray);
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error);
            }
          };

        getOpeningHours();
    
        if(openHours && openHours.length !== 0){
            setOpenHours(openHours);
            setSelectedStartHour(null);
            setSelectedEndHour(null);
            setStartHour(null);
            setEndHour(null);
        }
    }

}, [date])
```

and inside the return of your component only change the **state** of the date like this:

```
return (
    <DatePicker
        onSelectedChange={(value) => setDate(value)}
        // other props
    />
)
```

Comment: thanks very much , this was realy helpful , this have fixed my code , thank you again